# SML Create function receives list of tuples and return list with sum each pair

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm studying Standard ML and one of the exercices I have to do is to write a function called opPairs that receives a list of tuples of type int, and returns a list with the sum of each pair.
Example:

```
input: opPairs [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
output: val it = [3, 7]
```

These were my attempts, which are not compiling:

ATTEMPT 1

```
type T0 = int * int;
fun opPairs ((h:TO)::t) = let val aux =(#1 h + #2 h) in
                              aux::(opPairs(t))
                         end;

The error message is:
Error: unbound type constructor: TO
Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         [E]
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) h
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
fun opPairs2 l = map (fn x => #1 x + #2 x ) l;

The error message is: Error: unresolved flex record (need to know the names of ALL the fields
 in this context)
  type: {1:[+ ty], 2:[+ ty]; 'Z}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first attempt has a typo: `type T0` is defined, where `0` is zero, but then type `TO` is referenced in the pattern, where `O` is the letter O. This gets rid of the "*operand and operator do not agree*" error, but there is a further problem. The pattern `((h:T0)::t)` does not match an empty list, so there is a "*match nonexhaustive*" warning with the corrected type identifier. This manifests as an exception when the function is used, because the code *needs* to match an empty list when it reaches the end of the input.

The second attempt needs to use a type for the tuples. This is because the tuple accessor `#n` needs to know the type of the tuple it accesses. To fix this problem, provide the type of the tuple argument to the anonymous function:

```
fun opPairs2 l = map (fn x:T0 => #1 x + #2 x) l;
```

But, really it is bad practice to use `#1`, `#2`, etc. to access tuple fields; use pattern matching instead. Here is a cleaner approach, more like the first attempt, but taking full advantage of pattern matching:

```
fun opPairs nil = nil
  | opPairs ((a, b)::cs) = (a + b)::(opPairs cs);
```

Here, `opPairs` returns an empty list when the input is an empty list, otherwise pattern matching provides the field values `a` and `b` to be added and consed recursively onto the output. When the last tuple is reached, `cs` is the empty list, and `opPairs cs` is then also the empty list: the individual tuple sums are then consed onto this empty list to create the output list.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on exnihilo's answer, once you have achieved familiarity with the type of solution that uses explicit recursion and pattern matching (`opPairs ((a, b)::cs) = ...`), you can begin to generalise the solution using list combinators:

```
val opPairs = map op+
```